# Unable to link Spring boot application with Azure Application insight using application.properties, when logback.xml is used

Tags: spring-boot, azure-application-insights

I have created a spring-boot starter project and linked Azure Application insight to it. The properties like instrumentation- key is defined in "application.properties". On launching the application it is correctly linked to App Insight as can be verified by Live Metrics Stream.

However same application fails to connect to Azure App Insight if logback.xml is included in project (in resources), in this case to connect to App insight I have to include ApplicationInsights.xml as well.
But I do not want to use "ApplicationInsights.xml" in my application for 2 reasons. 1. I do not want multiple configuration files. 2. I am not able to inject key , i.e. not able to externalize key which might come as vm arguments or environment variable.

Defining InstrumentationKey and other configuration in application.properties works only when logback.xml is not present.

sample project (asset-register.zip) can be found at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/710

Comment: Post your configuration file while screening out sensitive data. Can't answer the question without that.

Comment: I have uploaded  a sample project at below location. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/710 and also could see that Spring application fails to connect to Azure App Insight if logback.xml is included in project (in resources), in this case to connect to App insight I have to include ApplicationInsights.xml as well. Defining InstrumentationKey and other configuration in application.properties works only when logback.xml is not present. And looks like the issue is not "spring security" as mentioned in the actual post, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: You should update your post and remove the erroneous assertion that spring security is to blame.